# Has anyone used Incanter in a web app to serve statistical graphs?

Tags: clojure, ring, incanter

I'd like to serve up statistical graphs based on Incanter with a framework like Ring or Compojure in a Clojure environment.  I haven't seen any examples or links that do this.  Could someone steer me toward working examples?  Would Enlive help out here as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

There is a tutorial entry about precisely that on the [Data Sorcery](http://data-sorcery.org/) blog: [Building a Clojure Web application with Incanter, Compojure, and Leiningen](http://data-sorcery.org/2009/11/29/incanter-webapp/).

(Data Sorcery is the official Incanter blog maintained by Incanter's author, David Edgar Liebke.)

Comment: See my answer to this SO question for links to materials on Compojure 0.3.x -> 0.4.x transtion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122749/good-current-documentation-and-or-tutorials-for-compojure-ring-development

Comment: See also my answer to this question for an up-to-date summary of the present state of one part of the Clojure web stack: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180688/what-is-the-good-starting-point-to-developing-restful-web-service-in-clojure